# Get notified when app is loaded in slide over

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios9, multitasking

Is there a way to get notified when the user switches to your app from another in the 'slide over' view?

I am currently overriding the traitCollectionDidChange method but this is only called when the app enters 'slide over' for the first time and on exit 'slide over'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sent a technical help request to Apple and got the response that basically 'there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations'.

So as of iOS9 I can safely say that there is no way how to get notified when the user switches to your app from another in 'slide over' view.